# 'as a body' vs 'in a body'

Tags: grammaticality, difference, prepositions

> [**in** a body](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-a-body?q=in+a+body)  = All together; as a group

I already understand and so ask NOT about the above definition.
Instead, my problem is: As a preposition, **in** confuses me. Why was **as** not used instead?

Am I right that this prepositional phrase is an idiom? Even if so, [what are some right ways of interpreting it so that it feels reasonable and intuitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571)

Footnote: I encountered this  while  reading [Etymonline for 'drove {noun}'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=drove&allowed_in_frame=0). I had been stuck for 5 mins before I suspected a figurative meaning and tried the dictionary.

Comment: Not sure but here is how **I look** at it-- when you **refer**, you do it *"as a group"*, and when you mean 'acting toward something', you call it *"in a group"*. Example: They came **in a group** and vandalized the premises **over** *"They are not different, consider them **as a group**"*.

Comment: I believe the choice of preposition is determined by the verb. Some verbs want "in", some want "as", and some don't care.

Comment: This might be something particular the BrE usage, or maybe just something falling out of favor in modern English. In my version of AmE, "in a body" is very uncommon when used in the same sense as "The workers went in a body to the rally."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an idiom.

Compare: in a group | as a group.

*They ran in a group to see the fist-fight taking place behind the gym.

The members of the book club went as a group to a Broadway play.*

In a {group, body} refers to the physical formation.

As a {group, body} refers to a set of individuals united in some common purpose or a set of items sharing a common property.